# org-mode quote block line feed missing

Tags: org-mode

Say below org-mode block:

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
item 1
item 2
#+END_QUOTE
```

If export as html, the display is:

```
item 1 item 2
```

It should be two line but actually merged as one line!
I wish to keep the line feed CRLF!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve newlines for the whole org-file you can use

```
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
```

If you want to preserve newlines only in quote blocks you can copy the following Elisp code into your init file. It defines a new keyword `HTML_QUOTE_KEEP_NEWLINES`. If that keyword is set to `t` newlines are preserved in quote blocks only.

```el
(require 'org)
(require 'org-element)
(require 'ox)
(require 'ox-html)

(defcustom org-html-quote-keep-newlines nil
  "Keep newlines in org quote blocks.
This is the default value.
You can set it buffer-specific with
,#+HTML_QUOTE_KEEP_NEWLINES: t"
  :group 'org-html
  :type 'boolean)

(setf (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'html))
      (cons
       '(:html-quote-keep-newlines "HTML_QUOTE_KEEP_NEWLINES" nil org-html-quote-keep-newlines)
       (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'html))))

(defun my-html-real-text-on-line-p ()
  "Return non-nil if there is more than whitespace and html tags on current line."
  (catch :found
    (while (null (eq (char-after) ?\n))
      (skip-syntax-forward " ") ;; skip whitespace
      (cond
       ((eq (char-after) ?<) ;; 1st case: beginning of tag
    ;; go behind the tag:
        (skip-chars-forward "^>") ;;< We even skip newlines here. It is actually an error if we fall off the edge of the world at this point.
    (forward-char)) ;;< Go behind the tag.
       ((eq (char-after) ?\n)) ;; 2nd case: Do nothing if we end up at an end of line.
       (t (throw :found t)))))) ;; 3rd case: No tag, no end of line, that is actually some real text.

(defun my-org-quote-preserve-linebreaks (quote_block_contents back_end info)
  "Keep linebreaks in QUOTE_BLOCK_CONTENTS when BACK_END is 'html."
  (when (and (eq back_end 'html)
             (plist-get info :html-quote-keep-newlines))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert quote_block_contents)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (null (eobp))
    (when (my-html-real-text-on-line-p)
      (end-of-line)
      (insert "<br/>"))
    (forward-line))
      (buffer-string))))

(add-hook 'org-export-filter-quote-block-functions #'my-org-quote-preserve-linebreaks)
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works fine! Would you please help give more details about the cond statement? Is it two condition true then throw exception? what's the meaning of this statement? `((eq (char-after) ?\n))`, I deleted it and works also!

Comment: @lucky1928 I have refactored and commented the code. That should solve your question what `cond` does. `((eq (char-after) ?\n))` checks whether the character at point is a newline. We do not want to interpret that as real text on that line and leave the `cond` form before throwing the `:found t`. Please use `C-h f` to read the documentation string of the function you want to know more about, e.g., `<C-h f> cond <RET>`.